# How to write a Keep screen on/off code using switch/button?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a settings app where there is an on/off switch or button to keep the screen on and off (a checkbox is fine too).

If the switch is ON, the app must be on as long as the app is closed. When the button is clicked off, the app's screen can go off.

I am a complete beginner in coding.

Comment: What part of this do you need help with, exactly?

Comment: the coding part sir

Answer (score 2):

**solution 1**

add this line in some widget  in xml

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

**solution 2**

before `setContentView` add flag like this

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
setContentView(R.layout.layout);
```

for off screen

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method :

**JAVA** code :

```java
MySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.ScreenController);
        MyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.StatusText);

        MySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                             boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){

                    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                    MyText.setText("Keep screen ON");

                    }else{

                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                    MyText.setText("Keep screen OFF");

                    }
                }
            });
```

**XML** [Layout] code :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Switch
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/ScreenController"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Keep Screen OFF"
        android:layout_below="@id/ScreenController"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/StatusText"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Very easy :) Hope to be useful.

Comment: Thank you...can this be added to SettingsActivity in android studio?